# How to step through code without going through auto-generated code?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

So I am debugging my Java application, but it steps through some auto-generated code? How can I stop this? Maybe I need to go to Options? This is in the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: There is not much code to show. It's just a question of using netBeans.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: @EdwardKarak- OK that's fine. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In netbeans use this question [How do I configure NetBeans to only step through Java code that I've written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875983/how-do-i-configure-netbeans-to-only-step-through-java-code-that-ive-written?rq=1#answer-2876131)

In eclipse go to

Window->Preferences->Java->Debug->Step Filtering

Check the box to "Use Step Filters" and check all the boxes for packages you dont want to go into.

Comment: And also, I have another question: How do I debug in general? I know you press F7 key, but the compiler completely ignores breakpoints.

Comment: @EdwardKarak According to my netbeans (6.9.1) you have to press ctrl+F5. Its also that big green play button with the page behind it. Also if your breakpoints are not being hit make sure your breakpoints are on a real executing line of code. meaning not on a comment and not in white space and inside a method, also be sure that method is actually being called :)